# NoMethodError in Ruby on Rails calling Class Method from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just learning RoR and have run into my first real bug. Would really appreciate some guidance with it. I am up to the point of creating a user sign in/out feature for a site I am building which will be maintained through sessions. When the sign in form submits it goes to a sessions controller which calls the 'create' method. When it does this it displays this error:

> NoMethodError in
>   SessionsController#create
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of ActiveRecord::Base. The
>   error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Here's the code for the create method:

```
  33 def create
  34   user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
  35                           params[:session][:password])
  36   if user.nil?
  37     flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
  38     @title = "Sign in"
  39     render 'new'
  40   else
  41     sign_in user
  42     redirect_back_or user
  43   end
  44 end
```

The application trace says the error is at

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:34:in `create'

So the issue seems to be with the authenticate method. This is a class method defined for my user object. What's weird is that I tested the method in rails console and it works fine. Below is the full trace. Again would be very grateful for some help with this. Thanks you.

Trace:

> app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:34:in
>   `create' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in
>   `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in`
>   *run*_4224187041876590211__process_action_*3718750575726612430*_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in
>   `_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`
>   block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in
>   `block in instrument' activesupport
>   (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`
>   instrument' activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in`
>   process' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in
>   `process' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in`
>   dispatch' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in
>   `dispatch' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in`
>   block in action' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in`
>   dispatch' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in
>   `call' rack-mount (0.6.14)
>   lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in`
>   block in call' rack-mount (0.6.14)
>   lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in
>   `block in recognize' rack-mount
>   (0.6.14)
>   lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in`
>   optimized_each' rack-mount (0.6.14)
>   lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in
>   `recognize' rack-mount (0.6.14)
>   lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in
>   `call' rack (1.2.2)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in`call' activerecord (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in
>   `block in call' activerecord (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in`
>   cache' activerecord (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in
>   `cache' activerecord (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in`
>   call' activerecord (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in`
>   block in call' activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in
>   `_run_call_callbacks' actionpack
>   (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in`
>   call' rack (1.2.2)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in
>   `call' railties (3.0.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in
>   `call' activesupport (3.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`
>   call' rack (1.2.2)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
>   <internal:prelude>:10:in`synchronize'
>   rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in`
>   call' railties (3.0.4)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
>   railties (3.0.4)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`
>   method_missing' railties (3.0.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in
>   `call' rack (1.2.2)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in`
>   call' rack (1.2.2)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in
>   `service'
>   /Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in`
>   service'
>   /Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in`
>   block in start_thread'

Comment: Ah didn't realize you were supposed to do this. Went through my answers and fixed this.

Comment: Check the value of params[:session]. is it actually an array? I suspect it's nil. And post the form that posts to this action.

Comment: Hi Thilo, I checked the form and I see I had the :session variable as ":sessions" which was causing the problem. It's fixed now. Thank you for your reply. If you'd like to submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params[:session]` doesn't exist

```
def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                        params[:session][:password]) if params[:session]
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring method `authenticate` in `class << self` : 
`class << self
  def authenticate(email, submitted_password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      (user && user.has_password?(submitted_password)) ? user : nil
  end
 end`

Try this: `def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)`. Be careful, you have to declare it out of `class << self`

In this case you are declaring a class method `authenticate` and you should able to call it in your controller, in the `create` method.